AppLocalizations Flutter
I can't understand why I shall duplicate the initialization of localizations in my app and my HomePage stateful widget I call (I tried also to change my HomePage as a StatelessWidget it's the same problem).
If I call the intialization in my HomepAge only it does not work, if I call the initailization in the App it does not work..
The only way I found to solve it's to duplicate code in both, else I have a null localization.
Any idea? I don't like duplicate code ;)
My code with duplicate init:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

import '';
import 'navbar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const PApp());
}

MyApp :
class PApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const PApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en'), 
        Locale('fr'), 
      ],
       theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),

      home: const PHomePage(title: ''),

    );
  }
}

Homepage :
class PHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<PHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<PHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      localizationsDelegates: [
       AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en'), 
        Locale('fr'), 
      ],
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: Navbar(),
        appBar: AppBar(
     
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.maintitle),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('',
           style : TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0)
        ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Use MaterialApp only in the root of your app
//After removed MaterialApp from PHomePage
class PHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<PHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<PHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return  SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: Navbar(),
        appBar: AppBar(

          title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.maintitle),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('',
              style : TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0)
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

